# Octave: LaTeX tics

Tags: plot, octave

In GNU Octave I would like to set the tics of a plot as fractions. So instead of 0.0078125 (which is equal to 1/128) I would like to write "\frac 1 128".

I tried already

```
set(gca,'xTickLabel',{'\frac 1 128'});
```

but it does not work. The text '\frac 1 128' is not interpreted as LaTeX code.

Comment: But `\frac 1 128` is not LaTeX syntax, it should be `\frac{1}{128}`...

Comment: Sure it is. But anyway, also `'\frac 1 128'` does not work...

Comment: But does `'\frac{1}{128}'`?

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant: Also `'\frac{1}{128}'` does not work...

Comment: What about explicitly setting the interpreter to TeX? (I don't know if Octave has LaTeX support yet) `h = get(gca, 'xTickLabel'); set(h,'interpreter', 'tex')`

Comment: "latex" isn't implemented yet. You can use a subset of TeX to display greek symbols, for example. If it's not important to have Latex in the plot but only in the generated print (for example for publication) I suggest using pdflatex or epslatex and render it with latex: http://wiki.octave.org/Printing_with_FLTK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`latex` isn't implemented yet in GNU Octave. You can use a subset of TeX for Greek symbols and so on.

If you just want to have LaTex in the generated print (for publication), you can use for example the device `epslatexstandalone` and render it afterwards with `latex`:

```
close all
graphics_toolkit fltk

title ("for thyme:")

t = linspace (0, 2 * pi, 100);

plot (t, sin (t))
set (gca, "xtick", [0 0.5 1 1.5 2] * pi)
set (gca, "xticklabel", {'$0$', '$\frac{\pi}{2}$', '$\pi$', '$\frac{3\pi}{2}$', '$2\pi$'})
grid on
set(gca, "fontsize", 20);

print -depslatexstandalone thyme

## process generated files with pdflatex
system ("latex thyme.tex");

## dvi to ps
system ("dvips thyme.dvi");

## convert to png for stackoverflow
system ("gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r100x100 -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=thyme.png thyme.ps")
```

[image: sin with latex]

Comment: Nice trick, but this isn't working when the plot has a logarithmic scale...bah, the trick works, the latex output has a bug. https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50130